# phone field on task not fill automatically

Tags: administration, tasks, standard-objects, configuration

I have a strange problem related to the standard phone field on task object.

From the documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_fields.htm&type=5, it is said that :

> the phone field contains the phone number of the contact or lead
>   related to the task. This field is filled in with the value from the
>   related contact or lead record.

But when when I choose a contact from the name field and save my task the phone field is not updated, even though on my contact page I do have the phone number fill.

Is this a restriction on using person account? I don't see anywhere saying that this field is not populated if I am using person account.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. It's not possible to Query `Task.Phone` field directly either (at least for me, it doesn't appear as part of the schema despite being listed under the Object properties in setup), Furthermore querying `Who.Phone` and `What.Phone` doesn't return any values even if the related records do.